# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string <builtin>: recipe for target 'wfdbinit.o' failed in WFDB octave toolbox installtion

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, octave

I need to work by EEG signals and trying yo use [WFDB from physionet](https://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb.tar.gz) site from [this instruction](https://archive.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-linux-quick-start-old.shtml), so based of its readme.MD file i tried to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc libcurl4-openssl-dev perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3).
libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8).
perl is already the newest version (5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.
```

When I try to `sudo make`, I get this output:

```
$ sudo ./configure
Checking the operating system type ...
Configuring the WFDB software package for Linux-64.
Checking the echo command ...

Looking for the C compiler ... gcc
Looking for the command to strip debugging metadata ... strip
The WFDB software will be installed in '/usr/local'.
The manual pages will be installed in '/usr/local/share/man'.

Looking for libcurl ... found
The WFDB software will be compiled with NETFILES access
using libcurl.

Creating Makefile in lib ...
Creating Makefile in app ...
Creating Makefile in checkpkg ...
Creating Makefile in convert ...
Creating Makefile in data ...
Creating Makefile in doc ...
Creating Makefile in doc/wag-src ...
Creating Makefile in doc/wpg-src ...
Creating Makefile in doc/wug-src ...
Creating Makefile in examples ...
Creating Makefile in fortran ...
Creating Makefile in psd ...
Creating Makefile in wave ...
Creating Makefile in waverc ...
Creating Makefile in xml ...
Creating Makefile in . ...
rm conf/site.def conf/site-slib.def

IMPORTANT: You have chosen to build a dynamic (shared) WFDB library in
a directory, /usr/local/lib, that is not normally searched for such
libraries.  In order to use the applications that will be compiled
with this library, it may be necessary to add this directory to your
LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  If your shell is csh or a variant, do this by
typing:
  setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
Otherwise, do this by typing:
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Summary:

wfdb-10.6.2-Linux-64 is now ready to be compiled using 'gcc'.
The WFDB library will be compiled as a dynamic library with NETFILES
 access via libcurl, and it will be installed in '/usr/local/lib'.
The WFDB library .h files will be installed in '/usr/local/include/wfdb'.
The WFDB applications will be linked to dynamic system libraries, and
 they will be installed in '/usr/local/bin'.
WAVE will not be compiled.
Manual pages will be installed in subdirectories of '/usr/local/share/man'.
Sample data files will be installed in '/usr/local/database', which
 will be included in the default WFDB path.

If you need to compile a different WFDB library type, or install into different
directories, rerun this script with its "-i" (interactive) option:
      ./configure -i
Other options can be viewed by rerunning this script with its "-h" option:
      ./configure -h

WFDB software configuration is complete.
Now run 'make' to compile and test, followed by 'make install' to recompile
and install the software, man pages, and example data.  Finally, run
'make check' to verify that the installation is complete and successful.

so@so-notebook:/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2$ sudo make 
make WFDBROOT=`pwd`/build LIBDIR=`pwd`/build/lib install
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2'
cd lib;      make clean; make install
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
rm -f wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o libwfdb.* *.dll *~
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
make clean      # force recompilation since config may have changed
make[3]: Entering directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
rm -f wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o libwfdb.* *.dll *~
make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
make all
make[3]: Entering directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
make setup
make[4]: Entering directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
sed "s+DBDIR+/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/build/database+" <wfdblib.h0 >wfdblib.h
make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
make wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o
make[4]: Entering directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
gcc -Wno-implicit -Wformat  -fpic -g -O -DWFDB_MAJOR=10 -DWFDB_MINOR=6 -DWFDB_RELEASE=2 `curl-config --cflags` -I/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/build/include   -c -o wfdbinit.o wfdbinit.c
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
<builtin>: recipe for target 'wfdbinit.o' failed
make[4]: *** [wfdbinit.o] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
Makefile:224: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
Makefile:230: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2/lib'
Makefile:268: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2'
Makefile:263: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

some more info based of [this](https://archive.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-linux-quick-start-old.shtml) :

> Install gcc, libcurl, and perl (requires root permissions). Check to
>   see if they are installed already using the commands
>
> ```
> gcc --version 
> curl-config --version
> perl --version
> ```
>
> If these commands work, skip to the next step. Otherwise, on Fedora
>   and other RPM-based GNU/Linux distributions, the command

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

so@so-notebook:/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2$ curl-config --version
libcurl 7.58.0
so@so-notebook:/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave/Biomed/wfdb/wfdb-10.6.2$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 67 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2017, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

so asked here about the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably the result of your choice to use an apostrophe in your directory name `Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/AI/Octave`

Comment: yes that was but how could i solve it without changing the directory by copying  in new directory?

Comment: You would probably need to edit the Makefile (or the Makefile.in) to quote or otherwise shell-escape all the filepaths - IMHO that's a rabbit hole that's just not worth going down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to compile the code in your home directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb.tar.gz
tar -xf wfdb.tar.gz
cd wfdb-10.6.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

as it will be installed in `/usr/local` by the way.